# How to add a second zfs hard drive to laptop

Tags: hard-drive, zfs

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop with a SSD 128GB drive. The SSD drive uses the ZFS filesystem.

I have also installed a 1TB 'regular' hard drive. When I installed Ubuntu, I did not get the option to format this drive in addition to the SSD. I would like to simply format and partition this extra drive so that i can use it as extra storage. I have only found very old threads about this which do not seem to help. Please can you help with the following:

1. How can i format this 1TB drive now?
2. What tools can i use to format it?
3. How can i get it to automatically mount when i start the system?

Thanks
Thanks

Comment: For your 1TB drive, do you want ZFS or EXT4? Also, is your computer setup to use UEFI or plain BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

There are some alternatives:

- **Format the HDD as any filesystem (eg. EXT4)** (recommended) and allow mounting through fstab.
- **Create another pool and import at boot** (advanced). Run `zpool create <name> <vdev>` and set mount point (`zfs set mount point`).
- **Move the pool to the HDD and use the SSD as cache/log** (geek). Create one partition on the 1 TB drive, then run `zpool replace <pool> <origin vdev> <target vdev>`. Once resilvering finished and the origin vdev is detached, you may repartition the SSD by removing everything but the EFI partition (assuming you have it), then, make partitions for SWAP, cache and log (16 to 32 GB for each would be enough). GRUB will detect the pool at the newer location; run `update-grub` and `update-initramfs` to ensure the system is bootable. This was my setup in my old laptop.

Never **ever** try to add the vdev in the HDD as non-redundant to the existing pool, because if the vdev in the HDD is missing, the pool renders inaccessible.

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/index.html) at the Oracle Solaris documentation page.